# How can i list some of my emails from my inbox in gmail using google api v3.0?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-api

This code show Labels i'm not sure what does it do or give.
The code is working.

But now i want to list in the listBox1 let's say the last 50 emails i have in my gmail listBox.
I already created a client_secrets.json file and inside the file i have my gmail account...my@gmail.com and also the client secret code and the client id.

This is what i tried but getting some errors:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Google_Gmail
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Youtube Uploader";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ListMessages(GmailService,)


        }

        private GmailService GmailService()
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Gmail API service.
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Labels.List("me");

            return service;
        }

        public static List<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message> ListMessages(GmailService service, String userId, String query)
        {
            List<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message> result = new List<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message>();
            UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List(userId);
            request.Q = query;

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    ListMessagesResponse response = request.Execute();
                    result.AddRange(response.Messages);
                    request.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                }
            } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));

            return result;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The first error is on the line:

```
static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly };
```

On GmailService i'm getting error:

Error   1   'Google_Gmail.Form1.GmailService()' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

The second this is what should i add in the constructor when calling the method ListMessages as userid and query ? userid is the client id i have in the json file ? And what should be the query ?

Comment: Ok found that i called by mistake my method GmailService changed it to GmailServices solved all errors. Now working.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling I found this

First you have to obtain the [list of messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list)
as you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) the `Message` object contains the immutable ID of the message, after that use the [get method](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) with a foreach loop with the messages list to retrieve the last 50 email addresses.

All three links have proper .net documentation